# Geocoding localities (towns/cities) with Google geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Is there a way to restrict the Google geocoding API to search only for settlements as opposed to full addresses?  The API documentation specifies a 'components' argument but that seems intended to specify a specific locality rather than localities in general.

For example a search for the town of Maskiot in Israel..

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Maskiot&sensor=false&components=country:IL
```

returns 'Maskit Street' near Tel Aviv, but the actual place I'm after is miles away, as a Google Maps search shows:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Maskiyot/@32.3178645,35.502754,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x151cf24adf97e761:0x4c10482c54ff115c
```

Very grateful for advice.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the result of the fact that you misspelled the name of the place.

In your original request you were using "Maskiot" whereas the place is actually "Maskiyot". If you change this name in your original request it all works fine.

Comment: That's how the data arrived

Comment: @geotheory I do not fully understand what you mean... When you quote Google Maps search you have there "Maskiyot" whereas the search term for Geocoding API is "Masciot"... So, it is no wonder that the results of these searches are different

Comment: I mean it doesn't matter if the name I was trying to geocode was miss-spelt - that's how it was in the dataset I was working with.  Geocoding often means dealing with different spellings.  Often when the place names are in a different language AND alphabet there no consensus on what the correct English spelling should be..